# Display all registered users Posts and Following

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code I've tried. It only displays posts of the current user
Here is the image of the firebase database to describe what I am trying to do:

[image]

I don't mind if the answer comes in java code too.
I appreciate your assistance.

```
private fun retrievePosts() {

    progressBar!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Catalog").child(uid!!)

    postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            (postList as ArrayList<ModelPost>).clear()

            for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                val post = snapshot.getValue(ModelPost::class.java)

                for (id in (followingList as ArrayList<String>)) {
                    if (post!!.getUid() == id) {
                        (postList as ArrayList<ModelPost>).add(post!!)

                        progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
                    }

                    adapterPost!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            progressBar!!.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only reading the posts of the current user from the database with this: `val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Catalog").child(uid!!)`.

To read the posts from all users, you should initialize `val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Catalog")`, and then add an extra loop (across the user nodes) in your `onDataChange`.

So something like:

```
val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Catalog")

postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
    (postList as ArrayList<ModelPost>).clear()

    for (userSnapshot in p0.children) {
        for (snapshot in userSnapshot.children) {
            val post = snapshot.getValue(ModelPost::class.java)
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks so very much for the answer. It worked out well.  Though I left something missing out.  I have a node that captures users following a specific user. If user is in the node, I want to display the users posts and all following. I hope you can help on that too

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to perform an extra call to the Firebase API to load the data for that user. This is known as a client-side join, and is quite common in Firebase (and other NoSQL databases). The alternative would be to store the data that you want to display for each user in the node already. Duplicating data like that is quite common in NoSQL databases too.