# Make posts of user A followed by user B appear on user B page

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I like to make the posts of a user A followed by user B appear on user B's page.

Here is the code I have tried which is not working as intended. I can only get the post of a specific user.

If possible please, write code in Java language.

```
private fun checkFollowings() {
    followingList = ArrayList()

    val followingRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .child("Follow").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
            .child("Following")

    followingRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            if (p0.exists()) {
                (followingList as ArrayList<String>).clear()

                for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                    snapshot.key?.let { (followingList as ArrayList<String>).add(it) }
                }

                retrievePosts()
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}


private fun retrievePosts() {

    val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts").child(uid!!)

    postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            (postList as ArrayList<ModelPost>).clear()

            for (snapshot in p0.children) {
                val post = snapshot.getValue(ModelPost::class.java)

                for (id in (followingList as ArrayList<String>)) {
                    if (post!!.getUid() == id) {
                        (postList as ArrayList<ModelPost>).add(post!!)

                    }

                    adapterPost!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}
```

Following Node:

[image: Following Node]

Posts Node:

[image: Posts Node]

Comment: Just as on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236152/display-all-registered-users-posts-and-following) you will need to read data from higher up in the database, and then perform nested loops over that data.

Comment: Thanks again, it works fine.  However, I'm still in a fix somewhere else, it's nested to this question too. Can I ask here too please?